# org.bytedeco.javacv.CanvasFrame showImage is hanging

Tags: ffmpeg, javacv

An IOS device is uploading h264 files (3 sec videos) to a server. Each file is successfully readable by VLC.

Using FFMpegFrameGrabber, I grab each frame and try to display them using CanvasFrame.showImage as below. However, the method call hangs.

```
CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("ios");
canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
canvas.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
canvas.setResizable(true);
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file))
{
    try(FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(fis))
    {
        grabber.setFormat("h264");
        grabber.start();
        while(true)
        {
            Frame frame = grabber.grabImage();
            if(frame != null)
            {
                canvas.showImage(frame);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong in the above code?

EDIT#1: When I try to save the buffered image for the frame, a valid image is saved.

```
BufferedImage image = converter.getBufferedImage(frame);
File outputfile = new File("png_file");
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following also needs to be done...

```
    canvas.setCanvasSize(768, 1024); 
    canvas.setVisible(true);
    canvas.validate();
```